# Start Azure VM runbook with managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to run a runbook to start a VM using a managed identity. With a runas account it works but because Microsoft says it recommended to use a managed identity, I want to try it.

This is part of the script that I got from internet and that works with runas account:

```
$ResourceGroupName = 'test' 
$AzureVMName = 'test'   

$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Login-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
```

And this is the script that I tried to use now but does not work:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
 
$ResourceGroupName = 'test' 
$AzureVMName = 'test'   

"Starting Azure VM..."
Start-AzureRmVM -Name $AzureVMName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
```

I always get following error:

Environments

{[AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureCloud, AzureCloud], [AzureGermanCloud, AzureGermanCloud], [AzureUSGovernme...
Starting Azure VM...
Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.

I have tried many things but I cannot get it working...

Comment: Oh ok i see you are mixing Az and  AzureRM modules. you need to use `Start-AzVM` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/start-azvm?view=azps-6.3.0) and make sure you have this module 
`Az.Compute` in your automation account.

Answer (score 2):

As [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167200/thomas) has already suggested you are using 2 modules which are `"Az"` and `"AzureRM"` in the below code :

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
 
$ResourceGroupName = 'test' 
$AzureVMName = 'test'   

"Starting Azure VM..."
Start-AzureRmVM -Name $AzureVMName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
```

So instead use only `Az` module like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$ResourceGroupName = 'ansumantest' 
$AzureVMName = 'testVM'   

"Starting Azure VM..."
Start-AzVM -Name $AzureVMName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
```

I tested this in my environment using one VM with managed identity to start another VM.

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Install the Azure Az PowerShell module | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-6.4.0#:%7E:text=In%20those%20situations%2C%20you%20can%20install%20the%20Az,source%20and%20manually%20copy%20it%20to%20other%20machines.)